# Markov chain with infinite number of transient and positive recurrent states?

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

Is it possible to have a markov chain with an infinite number of transient states, and an infinite number of positive recurrent states?

Thank you!

Comment: Which textbook are you following? // Unrelated: would you be serially opening new accounts for each question you ask?

Comment: No textbook just lectures. Apologies that was an accident I thought if I entered the same email it would automatically link up with my previous question

Comment: And these lecture(r)s never explained the classification of states of a Markov chain?

Comment: Yes they did but I am confused. As a recurrent state is said to be positive recurrent if time until first return has finite mean. A transient state cannot be positive recurrent. So surely it is impossible to have infinite number of transient states and an infinite number of positive recurrent states?

Answer (score 2):

The chain must be reducible for this to happen. For an example, consider a nearest-neighbour random walk on the integer line, recurrent on the negative part, positive recurrent on the positive part, and with no transition from the latter to the former.

To be specific, consider that $p(x,x+1)=p_x$ and $p(x,x-1)=1-p_x$ for every $x$, $p_x=\frac12$ for every $x\leqslant-1$, $p_0=p_1=1$ and $p_x=\frac13$ for every $x\geqslant2$. Then every $x\leqslant0$ is transient and every $x\geqslant1$ is positive recurrent.